# Adding custom (guarded) field to Laravel 5.3 Auth

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to add a custom field 'role' to Laravel 5.3 User Auth. The role will determine whether the user is admin amongst other roles and so because the Auth scaffolding uses mass assignable attributes, there is a vulnerability.

Therefore I have changed my User model to:

```
protected $guarded = [
  'role'
];
```

RegisterController I have added my custom fields (a default user will have the role = customer);

```
   return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'facebook_id' => $data['facebook_id'],
        'linkedin_id' => $data['linkedin_id'],
        'avatar' => $data['avatar'],
        'token' => $data['token'],
        'role' => 'customer',
```

I am getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default >value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, >`facebook_id`, `linkedin_id`, `avatar`, `token`, `updated_at`, >`created_at`) values  (name, name@domain.co.uk, hashed password, , , , , >2017-01-20 17:21:16, 2017-01-20 17:21:16))

Can't for the life of me figure it out.

I was thinking that maybe I don't use the mass assignable input, but I have a feeling that may mess up the rest of the Auth scaffold.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to set the default role is to actually define it in the model

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'role' => 'customer',
    ];

    protected $guarded = [
      'role'
    ];
    //...
```

Now when you use the create method and don't pass the the `'role'` attribute, the insert will use the value `'customer'`

Comment: OK thanks, I understand how this works, I am still a bit confused as to why my initial method fails though..! Cheers

Comment: the whole point of guarded is you can not pass `create(['role'=>'foo'])`

Answer (score 0):

In your migration for the users table where you add the role field, you either need to set the field as nullable, or give it a default value, so that when you mass assign without it, the database knows how to deal with that field.

```
Schema::table('users' function(Blueprint $table){
  $table->string('role')->default('customer');
});
```

or

```
Schema::table('users' function(Blueprint $table){
  $table->string('role')->nullable();
});
```

if your code can deal with a null role value.